# In spring Container How @Autowire can track which dependancy to inject in setter Method

Tags: java, spring, reflection, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I can understand how `@Autowired` can track the the dependency of the value.How they identify which setter method to invoked in run-time using reflection. And set the value in appropriate method.

I want to understand internal code implementation of `@Autowired`. How they can work internally. I can also read this raw code `BeanWapper` & `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory` but I do not understand the actual implementation of `@Autowired`.

I can Refer these :-

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.java#L202

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blame/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/a95843a0684585e09dcb63c7ce06a04c7f16d72a

Comment: The "implementation of `@Autowired`" is that it uses reflection APIs to call methods or fiddle with fields. It sounds like you're really wanting to know about the dependency resolution algorithm, which to my knowledge is fundamentally the same as any dependency resolver.

Comment: I would understand that things dependency resolver. How the spring  container identify which dependency to inject in setter method.I can use reflection But Problem is that i only have Class and i can extract all things in Bean class and invoke the appropriate method . could you please help me to do that @chrylis

Comment: @sanketjaiswal read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html

Comment: In That docs does not have raw code implementation @chrylis